# django NoReverseMatch at /account/dashboard/1/

Tags: django

I have a problem when I want to visit the user dashboard. On each article there is a link to the user profile, however, when I click on the link I'm getting NoReverseMatch. I was doing troubleshoots for days but I'm not able to fix the problem. Any help on how to fix this error is more than welcome, thank you!

article.html:

```
    <a href="{% url 'guest_user' pk=article.author.pk %}"><h6> {{ article.author.profile.username}}</h6></a>
```

accounts>views:

```
@login_required
def guest_dashboard(request, pk):
    user_other = User.objects.get(pk = pk)
    already_followed = Follow.objects.filter(follower = request.user, following = user_other)
    if guest_dashboard == request.user:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dashboard'))
    return render(request, 'account/dashboard-guest.html', context = {'user_other' : user_other, 'already_followed' : already_followed})
```

articles>View:

```
def article_detail(request, pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=pk)
    comment_form = CommentForm()
    already_liked = Likes.objects.filter(article=article, user=request.user)
    likesCounter = Likes.objects.filter(article=article).count()
    if already_liked:
        liked = True
    else:
        liked = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            comment = comment_form.save(commit=False)
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.article = article
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'pk':pk}))
    return render(request, 'article/single-article.html', context={'article':article, 'comment_form':comment_form, 'liked': liked,'likesCounter':likesCounter,'already_liked':already_liked})
```

article>URLs:

```
path('<pk>', article_detail , name = 'article_detail'),
```

account>URLs:

```
path('account/dashboard/', dashboard, name = 'dashboard'),
path('account/dashboard/<pk>/', guest_dashboard, name = 'guest_user'),
```

[image]

dashboard-guest.html>

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}


{% block content %}

    <!-- PROFILE CONTENT -->
    <div id="profile-container">
        <img class = "profile-cover-image" src = "/media/{{ user_other.profile.cover_picture }}">

        <div class="profile-profile-image-cover">
            <img class = "profile-profile-image-img" src = "/media/{{ user_other.profile.profile_picture }}">
        </div>

        <div class="edit-profile">
            <div class="social-media-links">
                <span><a href= "{{ user_other.profile.facebook }}" target = "_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook-square fa-2x color-fb dec_none"></i></a></span>
                <span><a href= "{{ user_other.profile.linked }}" target = "_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin fa-2x color-linked dec_none"></i></a></span>
                <span><a href= "{{ user_other.profile.twitter }}" target = "_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square fa-2x color-twitter dec_none"></i></a></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-btns">
            {% if not already_followed%}
            <a href = "{% url 'follow' pk=user_other.pk %}" class = "btn-follow">Follow</a>
            {% else %}
            <a href = "{% url 'unfollow' pk=user_other.pk %}" class = "btn-follow">Unfollow</a>
            {% endif%}
            {% if user.post_author.all.count > 100 %}
            <i class="fas fa-camera-retro fa-4x awards"></i>
            {% endif %}
            {% if user.article_author.all.count > 100 %}
            <i class="fas fa-crown fa-4x awards"></i>
            {% endif %}


        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF PROFILE CONTENT-->
    <!-- PROFILE STAFF -->
    <div class="profile-controllers">
        <div class="profile-main-controller">
            <div class="containerce">
                <p class = 'boxce txt-center'><i class="fas fa-feather-alt fa-2x dcolor"></i>{{ user_other.article_author.all.count }}</p>
                <p> Articles </p>
            </div>
            <div class="containerce">
                <p class = 'boxce txt-center'><i class="fas fa-image  fa-2x dcolor"></i> {{ user_other.post_author.all.count }}</p>
                <p> Posts </p>
            </div>
            <div class="containerce">
                <p class = 'boxce' txt-center><i class="fas fa-mask  fa-2x dcolor"></i> {{ user_other.follower.count }}</p>
                <p> Following </p>
            </div>
            <div class="containerce">
                <p class = 'boxce txt-center'><i class="fas fa-hand-holding-heart fa-2x dcolor"></i> {{ user_other.following.count }} </p>
                <p> Followers </p>
            </div>
            <div class="containerce">
                {% if user_other.article_author.all.count and user_other.article_author.all.count > 100 %}
                    <p class = 'boxce txt-center'><i class="fas fa-award fa-2x dcolor"></i> 2</p>
                {% else %}
                    <p class = 'boxce txt-center'><i class="fas fa-award fa-2x dcolor"></i> 0</p>
                {% endif %}
                <p> Awards </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MAIN FUNCTIONS -->
    <div class="functions">
        <div class="profile-buttons" id = "profile-buttons">
            <a id = "btn_articles" href = "#" class = "btn-profile-buttons active">Articles </a>
            <a id = "btn_posts" href = "#" class = "btn-profile-buttons ">Posts </a>
            <a id = "btn_videos" href = "#" class = "btn-profile-buttons ">Videos</a>
        </div>
        <div class = "liner"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- POSTS -->
    <div class="container-posts" id = "container_posts">
        <!-- Original posts card-->
        {% if user_other.post_author.all %}
            {% for post in user_other.post_author.all %}

                    <div class="container-posts-card">
                        <a href = "{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">
                        <img src = "{{ post.image.url}}" class = "container-post-card-img">                </a>
                        <div class="posts_card_edit">
                            <span class = "ellipsis-edit"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-v"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        <!-- END OF POST CARD-->

    </div>
    <!--ENDPOSTS-->

    <!-- ARTICLES -->
    <div class="container-articles" id = "container_articles">
        {% if user_other.article_author.all %}
            {% for user_other in user.article_author.all %}
                <div class="container-article-card">
                    <a href = "{% url 'article_detail' pk=article.pk %}" class = "article-card-btn">
                    <img src = "{{ article.image.url }}" class = "container-article-card-img">
                    <div class="article-card-details">
                        
                        <h6 class = "container-article-card-title">{{ article.title }}</h6>
                        
                        <p class = "article-card-created">{{ article.publish_date }}</p>
                    </div></a>
                    <div class="container-article-card-edit">
                        <span class = "ellipsis-edit"><i class="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i></span>
                    </div>

                </div>   
            {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <div class="container-article-card">
                <p>No Articles</p>
            </div>    
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <!-- ENDARTICLES-->


    <!-- END OF MAIN FUNCTIONS -->
    <br>

{% endblock %}
```

single-article.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <!-- CONTENT -->
    <div id="container-single-post">
        <div class="left-side">
            <img class = "single-article-img" src = "{{ article.image.url }}">
            <div class="single-post-author">
                <img class = 'single-post-author-image' src = "{{ article.author.profile.profile_picture.url}}" style="object-fit:cover">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
            <a href="{% url 'guest_user' pk=article.author.pk %}"><h6> {{ article.author.profile.username}}</h6></a>
            {% if article.author.profile.full_name %}
            <span span = "single-post-att">{{ article.author.profile.full_name}}</span>
            {% else %}
            <span span = "single-post-att"></span>
            {% endif %}

            <span span = "single-post-att">{{ article.category }}</span>
            <span span = "single-post-att">{{ article.publish_date | naturaltime }}</span>
            {%for a in already_liked %}
            <div>{{a.user.profile.full_name}}, you are awesome!</div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% if not liked %}
                <a href ="{% url 'liked_article' pk=article.pk %}" class="bst_like_cls"><span class = "single-post-love" id="probaman"><i class="far fa-heart fa-2x"></i>{{likesCounter}}</span></a>
            {% else %}
                <a href ="{% url 'unliked_article' pk=article.pk %}"class="bst_like_cls"><span class = "single-post-love"><i class="fas fa-heart fa-2x"></i>{{likesCounter}}</span></a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>

        <div class="single-post-content">

            <h5>{{ article.title }}</h5>
            <p>{{ article.content}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="single-post-comments">
            <p>Comments</p>
            <!-- Display Comment -->
            {% for comment in article.article_comment.all %}
                <div class="comment-single">
                    <div class="comment-author">
                        <img class = 'single-comment-author-image' src = "{{comment.user.profile.profile_picture.url}}" style="object-fit:cover">
                        <span class = 'comment-author'>{{comment.user.profile.full_name}}<a href = "{% url 'delete_comment_article' pk=comment.pk id=article.pk %}" class = "delete_comment">&times;</a></span>
                    </div>
                    <p class = "comment-date">{{comment.comment_date| naturaltime}}</p>
                    <div class="comment-author-content">
                        <p class = "comment-content">{{ comment.comment  }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <!-- END Display Comment-->
            <!-- POST COMMENT -->
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <form method = "POST" class = "form-comment">
                    {{ comment_form | crispy }}
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <button type ='submit' class = 'btn-default-comment'>Comment</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- END POST COMMENT-->

        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END OF CONTENT-->
<br>
<br>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the template, you have `<a href = "{% url 'article_detail' pk=article.pk %}"`, but the variable `article` is not created anywhere. Where should it come from?
There is a loop `{% for user_other in user.article_author.all %}`, and it seems like it should somehow lead to an article, but that's unclear without the models and business logic knowledge. Should it be  `{% for article in user.article_author.all %}` ?

Comment: def article_detail has context 'article'. I updated the post the full HTML is there.

Comment: it's not about article_detail, it's about the guest_dashboard and dashboard-guest.html. Please at least search for the code I've referred to before answering

Comment: that it's true, I completely forgot about that. I forgot to change other values. cheers! thank you!